# How to get the first day of current month measure with Year parameter in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-embedded

Seems like it should be very simple, but I still couldn't fine the way to get the first day of current month having parameter "Year"

So if parameter year 2018 - I need May 1,2018

if parameter year 2017 - need May 1, 2017

etc.

I tried to use DATE function, but the year will be dynamic.

How simply choose the first day of the month?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure how your year parameter is set up, but how about something along these lines?

```
FirstDayOfCurrentMonth = DATE([Year Parameter], MONTH(TODAY()), 1)
```

Comment: Thank you . But what `[Year Parameter]` should I place here? it wont let me use any Year(date) column from any table?

Comment: Try `MAX(TableName[DateColumn])` for the appropriate table and column.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you